# How can I restrict input field to enter upto 100

Tags: html, angularjs

I used min, max attributes

```
<input min="1" max="100" type="number">
```

Above input field is showing error on mouse over. i.e., "please select value that is no more than 100."

I want to restrict user to enter 1 to 100 and shouldn't show error message.

We should not allow user to enter more than two digit values other than 100.

Comment: call a function hover to show error and on over out  hide error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict user to put value in range in html input (type = number)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825843/restrict-user-to-put-value-in-range-in-html-input-type-number)

Answer (score 0):

Make a JavaScript code that make a restriction, so when the users enters a number below 1 it will be replaced with 1. And all numbers over 100 will be replaced by 100.

Code:

```
<input min="1" max="100" type="number" onchange="restrictValue(this)">
<script>
function restrictValue(input) {
    if (input.value < 1) {
        input.value = 1;
    }
    if (input.value > 100) {
        input.value = 100;
    }
}
</script>
```

If you want this to work while the user is typing, just change `onchange` to `oninput`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key events to create your restriction, so when the user type something you don't want, the value will change automatically.

```
<input min="1" max="100" type="number" id="myinput">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myinput").on('keypress keyup', function(){

            var max = parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
            var min = parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
            var val = $(this).val();

            (val < 1) ? $(this).val(min) : $(this).val();
            (val > 100) ? $(this).val(max) : $(this).val();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an directive to limit the number of charcters in the input feild. This is also compatible with old browsers like IE11.

```
.directive("limitTo", [function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);
        ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
            if (value.length > limit){
                value = value.substr(0, limit);
                ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
                ctrl.$render();
            }
            return value;
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Usage : `<input type="text" ng-model="test" limit-to="100" />`.

For my directive to work, `ng-model` attribute is required. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/31016/)

Comment: please share sample snippet code, not working for me

Comment: @VeeraBhadra: I have updated my example. Please check it.