# How can I take input from 1 to 10 only in HTML/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

How can I take input only `1 - 10`, (`1,2,3,4,...,10`) in HTML input tag?

If I enter `9` than the code should not allow me to enter anymore digits. And if I enter `1` than I can only enter `0` as the next digit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict user to put value in range in html input (type = number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825843/restrict-user-to-put-value-in-range-in-html-input-type-number)

Answer (score 0):

try below mention tag

```
<input type="number" name="numberInput" min="1" max="10">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
`for() {}`
Method for iterate input tag .