# How to restrict the input of numbers to a specific range?

Tags: javascript, html

I've set the min and max values and the input field type to 'number', but I can still physically input any numbers in the field, regardless of the range. How can I limit the input of numbers to only the required range, preventing values below or above it?

```
<input
 type="number"
 min='40'
 max='270'
 className="input-field"
/>
```

[input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXI3K.jpg)

Yes, warning will show if I will click any button in form, but I want to block exact ability to input anything outside the range

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825843/restrict-user-to-put-value-in-range-in-html-input-type-number

Comment: I would suggest that you don't edit your question with every suggested code change from the community.  It makes your question very hard to follow.

Comment: right @RobertHarvey, i create a answer for him but after post answer, checked he already updated his question so my answer is down for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use curly braces around the min and max values?

You should rather use single or double quotes:

```html
<input
 type="number"
 min="40"
 max="270"
 className="input-field"
/>
```

Comment: Did this, but still user can input any values outside this range. Only when any button is clicked in form warning is shown, but I want to block exact ability to input anything outside the range

Answer (score -1):

If you have set the min and max attributes on an HTML input field with the type set to "number," but users can still input values outside the specified range, it may be due to a couple of reasons:

Browser Support: Not all browsers fully support the min and max attributes for number input fields. While modern browsers generally do a good job of enforcing these constraints, older browsers may not. Ensure that you are using an up-to-date and widely supported browser.

HTML Validation: Make sure your HTML markup is correct, and there are no syntax errors. The input field should be enclosed within a  element with a submit button if needed. Additionally, confirm that the min and max attributes are correctly specified within the  tag.

Here's an example of how to use the min and max attributes:

Enter a number between 1 and 10:

Comment: <form>
  <label for="numberInput">Enter a number between 1 and 10:</label>
  <input type="number" id="numberInput" name="numberInput" min="1" max="10">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: better put your example in the answer rather than in comments @irfan